# How to change the starting index of iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We can use the following to iterate rows of a data frame.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

What if I want to begin from a different row index?  (not from first row)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using `itertools.islice`

```
from itertools import islice

for index, row in islice(df.iterrows(), 1, None):
```

Answer (score 94):

i know this has an answer, but why not just do:

```
for i, r in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
```

Comment: I'd prefer this way over `islice`. `iterrows` is can be very expensive (turning rows into Series); you still need to generate all the rows you're going to ignore before you get to the starting index specified in `islice`.

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
for i,(index,row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 0: continue # skip first row
```

Or something like:

```
for i,(index,row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i < 5: continue # skip first 5 rows
```

Comment: There might be a better way \*awaits other answers\*

Comment: thanks birnie :) me too was thinking there should be a better way than looping

Comment: The following is equivalent to @bernie's answer, but maybe more readable: `for index, row in itertools.islice(df.iterrows(),5,None):`.

Comment: it becomes very slow as number of iterations gets significantly high